# What is the correct way of routing different modules in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a project with three modules: auth, libros and prestamo, every module has different components and his respective routing and I have a general routing module for al the project, the code in my "auth-routing-module" is the next:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from '../auth/auth.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from '../forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from '../sign-up/sign-up.component';

const authRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'forgotPassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  { path: 'signUp', component: SignUpComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(authRoutes)
  ], 
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

I have a similar code in the other modules, and the code in my "routing-module" is the next:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren:() => import('../auth/auth.module').then(mod => mod.AuthModule)},
  {path: 'libros', loadChildren:() => import('../libros/libros.module').then(mod => mod.LibrosModule)},
  {path: 'prestamos', loadChildren:() => import('../prestamos/prestamos.module').then(mod => mod.PrestamosModule)}
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Finally this is the code of my "app-module":

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AuthModule, AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, when I check the navigation with the auth components the navigation works, but when I try to use a component of other module I get the next error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
    at Object.provideForRootGuard [as useFactory] (router.js:5749)
    at Object.factory (core.js:11468)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11385)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11205)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4728)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4732)
    at Object.RouterModule_Factory [as factory] (router.js:5714)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11385)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11205)
    at core.js:11242
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1213)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1167)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1279
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28497)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:582)
```

These are my first practices with Angular and I have no idea what are the "Lazy loaded modules" can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to call `RouterModule.forRoot()` multiple times in an application.

`.forRoot()` should be called only for the routes defined in the root module. For routes defined in any other routed modules you should call `.forChild()`.

So, keep the `.forRoot()` in the `AppRoutingModule` module only, and change `.forRoot(authRoutes)` to `.forChild(authRoutes)` in the `AuthRoutingModule`. Do the same for the routes of `libros` and `prestamos` module.

**Not directly related to the error:**
With your current route definition, to navigate to the `AuthComponent` you'll need the route `/auth/auth`. Consider defining the routes in `AuthRoutingModule` as -

```js
const authRoutes: Routes = [  
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'forgotPassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
    { path: 'signUp', component: SignUpComponent},
    { path: '', component: AuthComponent},
];
```

This will make `'auth'` the default route for the auth module and display the `AuthComponent` with the route `/auth`. Follow similar approach for the other two lazy modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make it as lazy loaded module by doing child routes in parent route module.
Refer this : https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes)` in your `AuthRoutingModule` and other two Feature modules.

`forRoot()` should only be used with your root module